# Are GET and HEAD mandatory methods?

Tags: http

I read on the Mozilla developer pages that the GET and HEAD methods are mandatory.

> The two mandatory methods, GET and HEAD, must never be disabled

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Is this information correct?

Does any RFC state this?

Is 405 Method Not Allowed not a valid response for a GET request?

If not, should I return a 204 No Content?

Comment: The result you return should match the reason. A GET can obviously return a 404 Not Found when the URL doesn't describe a resource held on the server. Other possible responses are Forbidden, Gone, etc. Now, for `PUT` you can imagine why you'd get a 405: the resource may exist as a read-only resource (entirely normal). But what exactly would a write-only resource be?

Comment: @MSalters, an authentication endpoint. Since it is an API it doesn't provide a HTML form.

Comment: I cant see that detailed anywhere in the RFC. If the target resource only accepts POSTed data it seems reasonable to respond with a 405 & Allow: POST - the spec for Allow: permits no value meaning that no methods are supported so its a bit confusing.

Comment: According to [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.1) `All general-purpose servers MUST support the methods GET and HEAD. All other methods are OPTIONAL.`

Comment: @Fred: That sounds like a URL which definitely exists, so a 404 or 310 would be misplaced. A 403 won't work (you're not looking at HTTP authentication). The 204 makes sense _for this specific example_.

Comment: @MSalters, yes the endpoint exists so a 404 or 310 would be misplaced. 204 makes sense, but so does 405. I wonder which makes more sense, 204 or 405.

Comment: @Fred as RFC 7231 talks about `general-purpose` servers you have to decide if your server falls in that category. If not you are fine to just return a `405 Method Not Allowed` based loosely on Paul Watzlawick "One cannot not communicate"